# Django Query writing

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

How to write below SQL query in form of Django Query

```
SELECT time 
FROM dispatcher_booking_timeline 
WHERE status = "completed" AND bookingId_id =
    (SELECT bookingId_id 
     FROM dispatcher_dispatch
     WHERE status = 0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have models that maps 1-1 with your SQL query:

```
status_zeros = Dispatch.objects.filter(status=0).values_list('pk', flat=True)
BookingTimeline.objects.filter(status="completed", pk__in=status_zeros)
```

Answer (score 0):

And than should be

```
booking_timelines = BookingTimeline.objects.filter(status="completed",pk__in=status_zeros)
times_set = set( booking_timelines.values_list('time', flat=True) )
```